# Alternative word for Karma, but when nothing is expected in return

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm creating a monopoly style game that allows people to "win" in any of these 3 areas:

- capitalism  (traditional monopoly)
- karma giving
- Giving with no expectation of return

I'm having trouble coming up with an appropriate term for that last one... something appealing, and suitable for a persons private scorecard.

The idea that I want to convey is that there are 3 different ways to play the game... and you can switch from one mode to the other at any time.  The last goal is similar to being an *anonymous donor to a charity*, or a giving to a homeless person *without* any fanfare.

**Question**

I looked at the word Karma, and in doing so I found this critique of the word:

> Karma alone is a dumb reason to do something for someone else

What is a better word for karma giving without expectation?

Comment: There is such a thing as a *gift economy*; the Burning Man festival is a modern example.

Comment: Karma Is already oblivious to the concept of reciprocity.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is *love*.

Comment: @Mitch, too bad people don't understand that. If you do a “good action” just because you want the karma, you actually lose it.

Comment: I don't understand Karma giving. May I know what you mean with that? In my opinion, the third case's word is Philanthropy and you need a good word for your second case too.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez well, it's not exactly hypocritical. I don't think I would want to disparage someone for being saintly because they want to be a saint.

Comment: *Charity* is the traditional, familiar word.  *Philanthropy* is the more officious, obfuscated term.

Comment: @RBarryYoung No no no. Charity is what the middle class give to the poor.  Philanthropy is what the 1% give to the 99%.  Remember, this is monopoly.

Comment: There are three ways to win in the game, "capitalism (traditional monopoly); karma giving; giving with no expectation of return". I'm not sure I understand the concept of this "karma giving" because "karma" isn't about reciprocity or any return as Mitch said. Any word or phrase that describes selfless acts would be a duplicate of the last option, more or less. Maybe your 2nd way to win your game is closer to what non-profit organizations do, i.e., they pursue their non-profit goals.

Comment: Additionally, how can you win by giving without expecting return, if you actually strive to win by this route, don't you just do it to win the game, hence expecting a return for it (winning)? ;-)

Comment: @FlorianPeschka - Maybe it's a game you can't win.

Comment: If you gave without expecting in return, but you enjoyed the knowing that the other party felt good because of your actions, you might be motivated by *compersion*.

Comment: @Ben if only compersion wasn't primarily used in the polyamorus communities

Comment: @LamonteCristo Nothing stopping the general public from co-opting the word for their own purposes. English already has so many 'borrowed' words from other communities (Such as the french and germans) after all ;) Evolution of language, etc

Comment: What about *idealism*? Not sure, whether it is more appropriate for category 2 or 3.

Answer (score 12):

[Philanthropy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/philanthropy)  is giving for the sake of giving.  Not for some reward in heaven or hope of a better reincarnation.  It fits with the context of the tycoons you play in monopoly.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps **altruism** (or selflessness)

> Definition: principle or practice of unselfish concern for; devotion
> to the welfare of others (opposed to egoism).
>
> Example: *Elephants are particularly altruistic. However, their altruism extends not only to other elephants, but to many other species in distress as well, including humans*.

"Compassion" is another possibility, but it refers more to emotion than action. However, **active compassion** may fit.

> Example: *Merkel's active compassion for refugees*.

Answer (score 1):

In Vajrayana Buddhism, we refer to doing good deeds or giving something with no expectation of return as, **"accumulating merit."** We strive to purify karma and accumulate merit and wisdom. When a great Tibetan master in our lineage was asked why he was doing the seemingly lowly task of re-stringing a student's broken mala (similar to a Roman Catholic's rosary), he replied, "Because it makes her happy, and I receive the merit." He did not need the merit, of course, but used the example as a teaching point.

**"Altruistic giving"** might be another possibility. Also, please note that **"Karma Giving"** could have negative or positive connotations in Buddhism.

Comment: Ah, but if doing good deeds with no expectation of return is "gaining merit", isn't "gained merit" an expectation of the deeds?

Comment: @HotLicks- Yes, some practitioners needlessly struggle with that ***in concept.*** In practice, it doesn't matter; it's just a name, a phrase used to convey the quality, not to be taken literally as though we were making deposits to a merit savings account!

Answer (score 1):

Many answers seem to focus on what the giving is referred to as. I think you may be trying to find the word akin to "karma", but without all of "karma"s connotations. I suggest **"mojo"** (or "vibe"). When you give without expectation of anything in return, you promote good "mojo" in a situation. "Mojo" doesn't seem to carry the same connotations of "karma" as it doesn't always return to you.

Answer (score 0):

If one can assume that most are familiar with the film, perhaps "Paying it Forward".  It would require getting legal protection from any perceived copyright violations.

Unfortunately I do not live near LA (or New York?) to volunteer to meet with Mr. Spacey and navigate that issue.

Comment: "Pay it forward" was a known expression before the movie.  And copyright would not apply to such a short phrase in any case.

Answer (score 0):

> Giving with no expectation of return

That kind of action is normally referred to as **selfless**—as in **selfless giving**, acting selflessly etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could have three incentive systems including material gain, spiritual gain, and gratuitous self-expression.  The last might be called art.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider [***generosity***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/generosity)

> 1. Liberality in giving or willingness to give: *a philanthropist's generosity.*<sup>1</sup>
>
> 1. willingness and liberality in giving away one's money, time, etc; magnanimity <sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>
<sup>2</sup> <sup><sub>Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003</sub></sup>